# Extract data from column to new column after groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to extract and split a column of data into two new columns. This is reasonably simple using `.str[xx:yy]`

However, I am getting an error when I am trying to complete the same after having run a `.groupby(["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"])[["aaa"]].count()` I get told that ***KeyError: 'Column name'***

As an example, after running the .groupby command, I get the following table:

```py
DevReg_df = DevReg_df.groupby(["Dev Loc", "Dev Model", "Dev OS"])[["Number"]].count()
```

```
+---------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
| Dev Loc | Dev Model | Dev OS | Number |          |
+---------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
| ar_ar   | Sam 22    | A 5    |      2 |          |
|         | Sam 4     | A 6    |      5 |          |
| az_ae   | i 1       | i 2    |      6 |          |
|         | i 34      | i 9    |     98 |          |
+---------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Running the following code afterwards gets me:

```py
DevReg_df["Language"] = DevReg_df["Dev Loc"].str[:2]

KeyError: 'Dev Loc'
```

The outcome of the table I am expecting is:

```
+---------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
| Dev Loc | Dev Model | Dev OS | Number | Language |
+---------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
| ar_ar   | Sam 22    | A 5    |      2 | ar       |
|         | Sam 4     | A 6    |      5 | ar       |
| az_ae   | i 1       | i 2    |      6 | az       |
|         | i 34      | i 9    |     98 | az       |
+---------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Edit: Reason that I don't want to do the commands in the reverse order (before the groupby) is that there are more than 30m rows which the groupby reduces to less than 100k. Doing the other way causes large delays in completing the script.

Comment: The column name is `'Dev Loc'` not `'Device Loc'`

Comment: If your problem is not the typo as mentioned above. `Dev Loc` is not a column anymore, it is your index after groupby.

Comment: @It_is_Chris corrected the typo

Comment: @Erfan thanks. So I have to create a new index?

Comment: No, just use `DevReg_df.reset_index()['Dev Loc'].str[:2]`

Comment: @Erfan thank you. Write it as the solution and I'll accept it

Comment: No need, this is probably a duplicate question and a basic pandas operation

Answer (score 1):

I think using apply and then splitting the series item might solve what you are looking for!! Try this

```
DevReg_df["Language"] = DevReg_df["Device Loc"].apply(lambda x:x.split('_')[0])
```